# Every Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\mu)$ converges in $L^2(\mu)$ to a function in $L^2(\mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

As I'm going over lecture notes, I'm still confused about the last part of the proof of this theorem. The proof has three steps: 1) construct $f$, 2) show $f\in L^2(\mu)$, and 3) finally show $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(\mu)$. My confusion is about the last step.

> 1. Pick a sequence $n_1<n_2<\cdots $ such that $\forall m\ge n_k$, $\|f_m-f_{n_k}\|< \frac{1}{2^k}$. Consider $$F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_{n_{k+1}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|.$$ We have that $$ (\int_X|F|^2 d\mu)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le 1.$$ Thus $F\in L^2(\mu)$ and in particular, $|F(x)|<\infty$ almost everywhere. So for most every $x\in X$, $$f_{n_m}(x) = f_{n_1} + \sum_{k=1}^{m}(f_{n_{k+1}}(x)- f_{n_{k}}(x))$$ converges as $m\to \infty$. Define $f(x)$ to be $\lim_{m\to \infty} f_{n_m}(x)$ when the limit exists and set $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

> 2. It is easy to show that $f$ is measurable. Also $|f| \le |f_{n_1}+|F|$. So $f\in L^2(\mu)$ since $f_{n_1}, F\in L^2(\mu).$

> 3. Notice $|f(x) - f_{n_m}(x)|^2 = |\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} f_{n_{k+1}} -f_{n_{k}} |\le |F(x)|^2$ almost everywhere. So by Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\|f-f_{n_m}\|\to 0$ as $m\to 0$. So for any $k$ and any $i\ge n_k$, $$\|f-f_i\| \le \|f-f_{n_k}\|+ \| f_{n_k}-f_i\|< \|f-f_{n_k}\|+\frac{1}{2^k}.$$ Now take limsup as $i\to \infty$ and the limit as $k\to \infty$ to see that $\|f- f_i\|\to 0$.

I can follow this note up to the point that $\|f-f_{n_m}\|\to 0$ as $m\to 0$. After that, I'm confused about the relationship between $n_k$ and $n_m$ and $i$. For example, the last few lines only writes $f_{n_k}$ and $f_i$. How do I use the conclusion of $\|f-f_{n_m}\|\to 0$ as $m\to 0$ there? In addition, I had a hard time applying the limsup as $i\to \infty$ and limit as $k\to \infty$. Dose it mean to apply limsup on $\|f-f_i\|$ and limit on $\|f-f_{n_k}\|$? I know that $\frac{1}{2^k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$. And maybe $\|f-f_{n_k}\|\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, because  $\|f-f_{n_m}\|\to 0$ as $m\to 0$?

Comment: This type of question has been discussed before at MSE not only for $L_2$ but for any $L_p$ $p\geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|f-f_i\| < \|f-f_{n_k}\|+\frac{1}{2^k}.$$ for all $i \geq n_k$. Hence $\lim \sup_{ i \to \infty} \|f-f_i\| \leq \|f-f_{n_k}\|+\frac{1}{2^k}$. This is true for all $k$ and letting $k \to \infty$ gives $\lim \sup_{ i \to \infty} \|f-f_i\|=0$.